# Incorporating photos into a Mathematica-made web page

Tags: export, image, html, internet

I use *Mathematica* to make [my web page](http://stanwagon.com). I make various .nb files, usually with photos, and then use an `Export` command to convert the .nb file to an .html file with auxiliary links and photo files. This has worked well for me...

... except: Once in a while the photos come out at poor resolution despite my best efforts. I have tried

```
Export["my.html", nb, "HTML", "GraphicsOutput" -> "JPEG"]
```

to guarantee that a jpg appears but I think it gets rasterized at a low resolution regardless of how high a resolution the pasted jpeg in the notebook has.

Has anyone run into this?

Any ideas how to force the `Export` command to generate the image file (whether a jpg or gif) at some minimum resolution?

Comment: Hello Dr. Wagon; can you try the setting `"GraphicsOutput" -> {"JPEG", "CompressionLevel" -> 0}` in `Export[]`?

Comment: Thanks. It sounds like just the thing....but it failed. I used:       Export[outputstring, Import[inputstring], "Notebook", 
  "ConvertClosed" -> "LinkedPage", 
  "GraphicsOutput" -> {"JPEG", "CompressionLevel" -> 0}]      But no change. It turned the source image of size about 6 mb to a jpeg have size 91 kb. So the compression is 65 times, which is of course a big problem.

Comment: I also tried the "ImageEncoding"->"Lossless" option. No progress.

Comment: That does sound very frustrating. :(

Comment: Does `PNG` fare any better as export format?

Comment: Try calling `Rasterize[img, ImageSize->512]` on all your images/plots etc beforehand (or whatever size you want instead of 512)

Comment: Re. PNG:  Yes I had tried that an hour ago and indeed it is creating larger image files, and the overall result is better. Rasterizing each of the many images in the file? Well I will try one as a test to see if that helps. But PNG seems to be a step in the right direction. A little frustrating though since there ought to be a way to get a JPG at appropriate size.

Comment: Sometimes I have also encountered  different frontend behaviour depending on whether an image is a `Graphics ` or `Image` construct. Perhaps you can supply more specific info or an example to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Is the magnification level of your notebook different from the default value? I used to store notebooks by saving images in a separate folder (note 1) (like an html page) and I had to make sure the image was rescaled when imported in a notebook with a custom magnification level. (note 1) I started back in the days when notebook corruption was rife but kept doing that to have small, agile, notebooks and externally editable pictures.

Comment: Magnification is default. The image cells look like                                                   Cell[BoxData[GraphicsBox[TagBox[RasterBox[CompressedData["
1:eJx    I have tried 2 ways of getting the jpegs into the nb. Main method is to use PhotoShop to resize the image to something suitable for the web, and then copy into M. This past week I used Import["image file"] which places it into M. This gives more control, and I can use things like ImageResize. But the problems all seem to arise from Export to html file, which acts in mysterious ways.

Comment: From what I remember the problem I ran into  (with older versions of MMA) was that the size of the imported picture could differ from the actual size of the saved image. Are all your image dimensions (X,Y of photoshop created image, nb imported image and html saved image) the same? Could it be that the stylesheet for the html version is forcing a different magnification?

Comment: Actually, I cannot reproduce this problem on OS X.

Comment: V10.1 on Windows  works o.k. with `"GraphicsOutput" -> "JPEG"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't seen a clear cut solution listed anywhere even though this question is quite old. Thus, I will post my solution here.
The easiest solution is to use SVG format rather than to fiddle with JPEG, GIF, or PNG format.

```
filePath = "path of the file";
nb = Import[filepath];
Export["my3.html", nb, "HTML", "GraphicsOutput" -> "SVG", "MathOutput" -> "SVG"]
```

This will make sure that your graphics and math output in HTML will be shown in high resolution.

For more information check out the wolfram documentation center, 
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/HTML.html 
especially under column "Options" → "Export options".

Comment: Thank you. I will try it.

Comment: This works well and might help out with some problems I had with my former method. But when I used the code thus:    

   Export[outputstring, Import[inputstring], "Notebook", 
  "ConvertClosed" -> "LinkedPage",
  "GraphicsOutput" -> "SVG", "MathOutput" -> "SVG"];

the font in the html file became Helvetica. My original file uses Times. Might you know how to control this?

Comment: Inside the notebook that you want to export, add the following code, Export["desktop.html", InputNotebook[], "HTML", "ConvertClosed"->False, "GraphicsOutput"->"SVG","MathOutput"->"SVG"]  .See if this creates a html file without the error.

Comment: Also check and see if other fonts are displayed correctly. For example, choose Georgia instead of Times.